# How I can control an AC 220v with a relay and a Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: sensor, relay, temperature, power-management

I'm a newbie in this topics. I love electronics and I love the power of the boards like Raspberry Pi and I want to learn to use it by myself learning in internet, but I have a lot of lacks of knowledge. For this reason I want to ask you for help.

I have a 2 type os birds in my house, I have hen and I have quails. I live in Spain in a zone that we can reach 42 celsius in the shadow. In our house we have not AC, we live with fans in every room (XD). But our birds haven't. I want that my animals can have the best confort as I can give it to them. For these reason I have thought that i could install a fan in his"room". My idea is to have a thermometer and an humidity sensor to calculate the temperature sensation. And create some rules to power on the fan or power off to let them sleep or in other words stop the noise.

I have experience with 3.3v relays but always I used with 5v DC and USB. Here in Europe electricity is AC with 220V and I saw that maye I must use some resistances and maybe other stuff.My bord is a Rasberry Pi 3B. Can you bring me a "design" or at least the main things that I need to build this project? Do it for my birds :) they will appreciate I think.

Thanks all!

Comment: I've voted to close this topic as any advice could lead you to killing yourself or others, burning the house down etc. **Mains can and does kill**.  Please consult a qualified electron before even thinking of going down this route.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this person does not have the correct skills to implement this and could end up killing themselves or others.

Comment: You can buy control devices for switching mains current using an Arduino or Raspberry Pi.  I am in the United States, and those I can easily find are for American wiring, but it is quite likely that similar products are available in Spain.  Here's an example with American specifications: https://www.amazon.com/Iot-Relay-Enclosed-High-Power-Raspberry/dp/B00WV7GMA2  As others have said, please do not try to build one yourself.

Comment: Look for some 'Home Automation' products, like Sonoff (https://sonoff.tech/product/wifi-smart-plugs/s20). There is plenty of information on using the Pi to control them or go to a system like OpenHAB. Dave

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, you may have gotten the advice not to start soldering with mains.  I would agree with them, though a solution exists.

In my home I use a remote controlled switching system, based on 433MHz. What I have is called "Klikaanklikuit" and the website of the vendor boasts that it is also available in Spain. But others exist.

If you wire a 433 MHz transmitter on your Pi, you do not need a 220V relay. As a shameless plug of my own website, https://dullaart.website/raspberry/2_433Mhz.html#a2 tells how I did it.

Please do not start with 220V if you do not know exactly what you're doing. It is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what other's have stated, unless you plan on wiring the relay directly into the mains, I do not believe your idea is that dangerous if you follow this advice carefully and gather some knowledge first.

- **First and foremost, never wire live cables.**
- **Never touch live wires, or leave them exposed, in any circumstance, unless you are a trained professional**

This would be my approach. I would choose a fan that operates through a plug socket with an RCD device. You can buy adaptors that incorporate these, [like this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Masterplug-Single-Socket-Safety-Adaptor/dp/B000RZDNZM/ref=sr_1_2?adgrpid=52734888905&dchild=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw0_T4BRBlEiwAwoEiAUuqWxwUHELfbdRoCe5_kGvLxeCp0KzVW_UQZb2EaLcLArB_EUpAdxoCuH8QAvD_BwE&hvadid=259041763568&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1006687&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=12174239402581302774&hvtargid=kwd-304762157673&hydadcr=25804_1822864&keywords=rcd+socket+adapter&qid=1595781386&sr=8-2&tag=googhydr-21).

What I would do is cut the plug lead to the fan in half, and strip both sides. **If you don't know how to strip and terminate plug cables, find out and learn before you try this!**

I would then have the relay control the fan connection with the socket turned on. **Make sure the relays you use are correct for you application, do some research!**

- **Do not go ahead with this unless you are 100% certain about your safety**
- **Ensure that absolutely no wires and circuitry are exposed (THAT MEANS IT'S YOUR RESPONSIBILITY TO PROTECT OTHER PEOPLE - YOU DON'T WANT TO BE RESPONSIBLE FOR SOMEONE ELSE'S DEATH) and do not touch the circuit at all while the plug is turned on and plugged in**
- **Plan your circuit, draw it out, test a dummy circuit not connected to the 220v wires and get the code right, take pictures and post it on forums like this and get advice about it before you turn it all on**
- **Check, check, and check again**
- **If you know somebody who has experience with domestic electrics, get them to help you with it. They might not know about the Pi, but they will know if your 220v circuit is safe.**
- **Learn about domestic electrics as much as you can through videos, books, internet. It's not a game and you will hurt yourself or somebody else if you don't know what you're doing.**

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOGltcgiXiU&t=580s) is a tutorial on Youtube of someone doing something similar, although the wiring is UK standard here, the principle is the same.

Please, please be careful.

[image]

Comment: Hi,

I wanted to connect the fan wire to a relay, and the relay to gpio with another plastic wire. I will see this video to learn how to do it. Thanks to be so nice